# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-py34

Tags: python

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to install `gattlib`. When i tried to install `gattlib`, there is a line `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -lboost_python-py34`, but i have `_python_py36`,so i get error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-py34`. How can i fix it?

Comment: Packaging is per-distro. Always specify your operating system (including a specific release and any relevant additional package sources configured) in this class of question.

Comment: I guess i explain wrong. Sorry, but i edited

Comment: try: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4843

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4843), it looks like you need to make a link by the following command:

```
sudo ln -s libboost_python-py36.so libboost_python3.so
```